# Why is my JSON message not encoded correctly in BizTalk 2016?

Tags: json, biztalk, biztalk-2016

I'm having an issue while sending a JSON message from BizTalk 2016 with the JSON Encoder component.

In my schema I defined an element as an array (minOccurs=0 maxOccurs=unbounded), but I'm only sending 1 element in my message.

```
 <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="ProcessOrders">
```

But in the JSON message it's not being presented as an array.

[image: json message]

I've been doing some searches and according to what I find, it should work when I define it in my schemas as unbounded.

But it does not seem to work as expected. Did anybody have this issue before?

Comment: Usually the only time you get that is if your XML payload has not passed through a XML disassembler and the MessageType has not been set.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf I'm using an XML Assembler and I can see in the context that the messagetype is promoted. So that part should be ok.

Comment: Have you looked at r3verse's answer?   About not having multiple elements with the same name in your schema with different definitions?  That does cause odd problems with the JSON encoder.  See "Issue: The BizTalk JSON Encoder applies same type to elements with the same name" in my blog https://cdijkgraaf.wordpress.com/2016/08/12/biztalk-2013-r2-known-bugs-issues-quirks/

Answer (score 1):

I just tested it and it creates an array when there is only 1 element just fine. However, there is one thing you have to keep in mind when working with the JSON Encoder: Only use the same name for an element once, so **ProcessOrders** should only be defined one time, if you also define it as your root element name (which isn't repeating), for instance, that one will be used as the definition for all other elements with the same name, and will not be recognized as repeating. Same counts for data types.